# Shared folder permission anomaly with linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

So, i have this shared folder symbolically linked to 'shared'. The folder is associated to 2 user (bill and karen) who both has membership of 'bill-karen' group. Problem is, i can't seem to create a new file from both user unless I run a new shell with `su - [USER]`

This seems odd to me as the folder is owned by **root:bill-karen** while the permission for the folder is 2775 (-rwxrwsr-x). Is there any reason behind this? I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS anyway.

How i configured the shared folder:
*Note that i already has user bill

```
sudo adduser karen
sudo addgroup bill-karen
sudo usermod -aG bill-karen bill
sudo usermod -aG bill-karen karen
sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/shared_folder
sudo chown :bill-karen /usr/local/share/shared_folder
sudo chmod 2775 /usr/local/share/shared_folder
ln -s /usr/local/share/shared_folder /shared
```

Then i tried creating a new file as bill|karen:

```
cd /shared
> foo.txt
```

It says bash: foo.txt: Permission denied

Comment: Is it possible that you're adding the membership of the group *after* starting the shell? Group memberships are not 'updated' if they change at run-time. By starting a new shell with 'su -', it initializes the group memberships again, which would add the group `bill-karen` to the group list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the same setup as you did and could not reproduce your issue.

I ran the following as root in an empty ubuntu 20.04 docker container:

```
useradd bill
useradd karen
groupadd bill-karen
usermod -aG bill-karen bill
usermod -aG bill-karen karen
mkdir /shared
chown root:bill-karen /shared
chmod 2775 /shared
ln -s /shared /link_to_shared
su - bill
```

Then as bill I was able to run this:

```
cd /link_to_shared
touch created_by_bill
exit
```

When logging as karen:

```
su - karen
```

I could do the following as well:

```
cd /link_to_shared
rm created_by_bill
touch created_by_karen
exit
```

I suspect something in your configuration doesn't match the description in your post.

Perhaps you modified the group membership recently and your currently open sessions have not taken it into account?

Try to run the `id` command to make sure that your users are in the expected groups:

```
$ id
uid=1000(bill) gid=1000(bill) groups=1000(bill),1002(bill-karen)
```

Comment: To be clear,

Lets say i logged in to bill and my current prompt is bill@bill-VirtualBox$. With only this, i can't create a new file in the shared folder. But, if i run a new shell again like such : ```su - bill```. Only by doing this can i create a new file. Also, i check my configuration and they have matched my description

Comment: To check the group membership. I tried ```groups bill``` and ```id```. Whats weird is bill-karen exist in the former but not the latter. Why?

Comment: `groups` reads configuration files, but `id` gives you the current context of your existing shell. Your existing shell is not up-to-date with configuration files since you configured the users' membership after opening this shell. Therefore you just need to exit those shells and both commands will show you up-to-date information.

Comment: I tried exiting the shell to make sure the commands have up-to-date infos. Unfortunately, ```id``` still have no bill-karen. Aside, does the shell being not up to date makes it also impossible to create a new file in my case?

Comment: Update: after restarting the machine the issue is gone